# Как реализовать подсветку кода Objective-C в статье?

Tags: веб-программирование, objective-c

Стоит задача реализовать подсветку кода Objective-C при публикации статьи на сайте. Каким образом это можно реализовать? Может плагин какой существует?

Answer (score 1):

Есть разные варианты, например, реализации на JavaScript (нужно добавить скрипт и стили):

- [Highlight](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/),
- [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/),
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Highlight хостится Яндексом, а Prettify - Google. Все они так или иначе поддерживают C-подобные языки, но насколько хорошо поддерживается именно Objective-C надо смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразователи в vim/emacs. На выходе html.